# problema com .env golang (iniciante) failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to [RESOLVIDO]

Tags: postgresql, golang, variáveis-de-ambiente

eu estou tentando conectar ao postgres usando o o golang, gorm e um arquivo .env pra colocar as informações de conexão com o banco. mas o golang emite o seguinte erro:

> C:/Users/PROGRAMAÇÃO-03/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.24.1/gorm.go:206
> [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to
> `host=open user=PROGRAMAÇÃO-03 database=`: hostname resolving error
> (lookup open: no such host) panic: failed to connect to `host=open user=PROGRAMAÇÃO-03 database=`: hostname resolving error (lookup open:
> no such host)
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: main.main()
> C:/Users/PROGRAMAÇÃO-03/Desktop/projetos golang/env/main.go:26 +0x406 exit status 2

Arquivo `.env`

```
DB_HOST = "localhost" 
DB_PORT = 5432
DB_USER = "postgres"
DB_PASSWORD = "ivaneteJC"
DB_NAME = "bd_testes_gerais"
```

Arquivo `main.go`

```
func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Erro ao carregar arquivo .ENV")
    }
    host := os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    port := os.Getenv("DB_PORT")
    user := os.Getenv("DB_USER")
    password := os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
    name := os.Getenv("DB_NAME")

    conexaoPostgres := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s"+"password=%s name=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, password, name)
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(conexaoPostgres), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("sucesso ao conectar", db)
    }

}
```

Consegui resolver o problema carregando o arquivo .env (inseri o load antes de setar meus arquivos .env na funcao main:

```
err := godotenv.Load()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
}
```